What is the rationale behind 32333 "Technic Pin Connector Block 1 x 5 x 3"?
I never had this piece so I bought a couple to play with.
I've found that the 3 dimensions I've labeled A are all the same, 3 units long. But lengths B and C don't connect with a standard beam. Knowing how much thought Lego puts into piece design, there must be some reason for the length, or a reason for the angle of the sides? It couldn't be arbitrary.

More to the point, what is this piece for?

This part was designed for use with the Technic Engine Cylinder 2850a (or  2850b). Like this standard V8 engine:

source
The strange geometry is due to the piston shafts needing to align with the lower central pin hole.
I've made a diagram to (attempt to) illustrate this. The three red triangles are the same shape.


Adding to this, the top center hole and holes directly adjacent to the bottom center hole are spaced in such a way that they provide a solid 3-point mounting arrangement for each end of the assembly as a whole when used as part of a larger Technic build. For example, set 42125 (Ferrari 488 GTE AF CORSE #51) uses this mounting approach, with the connections on the front-end of the engine block being clearly visible in the back of the cockpit.
